# Playing my Playsation 2 on a pc monitor

Tags: ps2, monitor

My problem is that I want to play my playstation on my pc monitor but am having difficulties because of the playstation 2 needing a Scart connection (or Red, white, yellow - i'm unsure of exactly what this is known as).

Does anyone know if its possible to get something to convert the signal from Scart to something my monitor will accept.The monitor has the following inputs:
- HDMI
- DVI
- VGA

Ideally I would like to use the HDMI port because that can carry the audio signal as well.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need something like this:

http://www.ramelectronics.net/audio-video/video-converters/composite-video-to-hdmi-dvi/v363/prodV363.html

The red, white, and yellow cables are known as composite cables, so you need a composite to HDMI/DVI converter.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed :) for the reference of anyone living in the UK (like me) I found this alternative on ebay http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/COMPOSITE-HDMI-CONVERTER-UPSCALE-720P-AND-1080P-/270716944874?pt=UK_ConsumerElectronics_VideoSwitches_SM&hash=item3f07fcc1ea#ht_3172wt_1139

Answer (score 2):

Buy an old PS3 with backwards compatibility for PS2 games. PS3s have HDMI output.

As a bonus you get to play with wireless controllers as well. Not exactly a cheap solution though...

Comment: This also crossed my mind but I already have a PS3 and the ones that are actually backwards compatible are so much more expensive